# White wine v cider vinegar

Tags: substitutions, sugar, vinegar

I am about to use a recently viewed tv recipe for Rhubarb ketchup. Official ingredients include white wine vinegar but does say any vinegar 'will do'. I have some cider vinegar, will this dramatically alter the flavour or sweetness? Might I have to alter sugar quantity?

Answer (score 2):

Cider vinegar is generally a little bit sweeter and not quite as sharp as white wine vinegar. With the other flavors you're adding, the difference isn't likely to be major. A good approach might be to hold back about a quarter of the sugar in the recipe, taste, and adjust to preference.

One thing in the cider vinegar's favor is that most of the acid present in the rhubarb is [malic acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malic_acid), the same compound that gives green apples their tartness. Apple and rhubarb typically get along quite nicely and I see no reason why they wouldn't here as well.