# Can I use apple cider vinegar instead of white wine vinegar for cooking?

Tags: pasta, vinegar

Can I substitute apple cider vinegar for white wine vinegar in a pasta and chicken dish?

Comment: Dorothy ... those two are generally similar in acid, so are reasonable compatible for most dishes.  See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/56960/67 .

Answer (score 1):

It may slightly alter the flavor (maybe in a positive way!). It shouldn't cause any negative chemical problems in the recipe. I sub different vinegars regularly and I haven't had any troubles.